# Model builder - Nesting models to extract raster values to points

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

[image: Random Point model]

Hello!
Hopefully a quick question.  I have a simple model below that iterates through a folder full of rasters, taking each in turn to extract data values based on a single shapefile of Random point locations.  The rest works over the points table to add a field named after the raster, calculates it from the RASTERVALU field, then deletes the RASTERVALU field.  That file is fed back into the model as the next raster comes through to repeat the process. The end result is a series of shapefiles where the final one has as many fields as raster, named after the raster, and with its values.

Now I want to do this for many shapes/feature classes of random points.  I have tried to use this is a nested iterator model with no luck.  When nested, I can pass the name of each random point shp so that it does not over-write the previous run, but in that case the raster iterator only works for the first raster.  I realize this might be asking a lot of the model builder, but maybe someone has a better idea fro nesting or a different logic approach.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_Multi_Values_to_Points/009z0000002s000000/) tool - this will copy the raster values into fields added to the original points file (no replication like the Extract Values to Points tool does). Then either [batch process](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_batch_processing/00210000000w000000/) with the different points files, or set up in model builder to iterate over your points files.

You may also consider adding a new identifier field to each points file and then [merging](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Merge/001700000055000000/) to one file for input to the Extract Multi Values to Points tool - therefore no iteration needed. However, for huge numbers of points this merge may tie up your computer for a long time.

Comment: Thanks ccn!  Perfect answer.  A new tool choice as well as new logic.  Thank you very much!